# Override a non virtual property

Tags: c#, inheritance

I know that in C# we cant override non virtual fields and methods but I have the following case:

```
Class Base
{
   public static int a {get;set;}
   public static void b()
   {
       // it uses a
   }
   public static void c()
   {
       // it uses a
   }
   public static string d {get {return a.ToString();}}
}

Class MyClass :Base
{
    //...
}
```

now in my class `MyClass` i want to override the property `a` that all of `Base class` methods and properties start using the the overwritten property that i implemented, taking into considerations that i don't have access to change `Base class`

Is there any way to do this even if i had to [re-implement](https://gist.github.com/joeenzminger/7526426) the getter method of that property?

Comment: why do you have all static methods!?

Comment: @DanielA.White it from a generated file from the .net framework

Comment: the .net framework does not generate classes (unless you tell it to) please elavorate.

Comment: @DanielA.White i was talking about resource files and "PublicResXFileCodeGenerator"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a static property, so it's used in the form `Base.a`. Whatever you do, the calling code will still resolve to the `Base` class, and then to it's static property `a`.

E.g

```
//old calling code
Base.a = 7; // does not create an instance
Console.WriteLine(Base.a);

class MyClass :Base
{
   public static string a {get; set;}
}

//new calling code
MyClass.a = "some string"; // uses whatever a you defined in MyClass
Console.WriteLine(MyClass.a);
```

Comment: Yes, you are correct, i was just a little bit confused. thank you

Answer (score 2):

The best way is perhaps to introduce a new property by a different name, or have your class wrap the base class instead of extending it. Together with extension methods, these are the most common ways to build upon functionality of a class you don't have access to.

You can also re-introduce the property using the `new` keyword, but I would not recommend that. It hides the base class methods, which is dangerous because users of your code may end up calling the wrong thing. Whether `new` is warranted in this case very much depends on your exact use case.

Finally note, as Daniel remarked in the comments to your original post, that the methods in your base class seem to be static. So even if you *had* base class access, you would not be able to make them `virtual`. Actually having loads of static methods is generally bad design, except special cases such as object factories or extension method containers.

Comment: That doesn't introduce override semantics, as the question requests.  There's also no need to use `new` to have a property of the same name in an inheriting class; with the properties being static there isn't anything to actually shadow.

Comment: Correct, the only way to get proper override is by making the base method `virtual`. Hiding the base class property and composition are the only alternatives I know of. They serve different purposes however, and which one is chosen depends on _why_ OP wants to do what they want.

Comment: The property is static, so it couldn't even be virtual if he wanted it to be virtual.

Comment: Yep, that is the other issue with the code, as remarked by Daniel in the comments already.